# Any reason why this code snippet wouldn't set a cookie properly?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

This little PHP snippet is used to set a cookie that lets me determine whether or not a user is logged in. For some reason, after I use the javascript to redirect, none of my cookies are set any more. Any reason why this would be happening?

I may not be giving you enough info so let me know if so.

```
...some database queries...
<?php 
    $expire=time()+(7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $email = $row['email'];
    $userinfo['name'] = $name;
    $userinfo['email'] = $email;
    $userinfo = serialize($userinfo);
    setcookie("user", $userinfo, $expire);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "../index.php";
    </script>';

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function setcookie returns true or false, depending on whether cookie was set successfully. You could try this to test:

```
if(!setcookie("user", $userinfo, $expire)) {
    echo 'Could not set cookie!';
}
```

If this returns false, then Kumar is right. Otherwise there has to be some other reason.

**EDIT** setcookie can be called with more parameters, like this:

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)
```

Notice the path and domain values. I have had problems in the past with two different pages not find each other's cookies because of different paths/domains.

I noticed that You redirect to "../index.php". Try redirecting to "index.php" and see if the cookies exist there. If yes, then You should use a common "path" variable to set cookies.

From http://www.php.net/setcookie about "path" variable:

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Comment: Rauni I feel he is setting cookie in a subfolder and then checking it at root, look at the path he is redirecting to, its not `./` its `../` so that may be causing issue

Comment: @Kumar I suspected this. How do I set it in the root?

Comment: use `/`, it will be set for root or use `domain.com` for path and it should work for you. look at my comment

Comment: @Kumar So, `setcookie("user", $userinfo, $expire, "/");`?

Comment: Glad that worked for you, next time when in trouble with PHP, just visit the url php.net/name_of_troubling_function, php.net has ability to send you to right destination on documentation

Comment: @Kumar Unfortunately `php.net` is down currently haha otherwise I would have done exactly that.

Comment: use the Google cache results :P

Answer (score 4):

Tory, make sure you do not output anything before you call set `setcookie` in PHP. Not even white space. No echo. Nothing. What I guess is your scripts outputs some thing before setcookie and that breaks your script. Do you see header already sent error? Comment out your JS and then check. You setcookie in this way

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure);
```

Domain needs a domain name value in string like `example.com`, its optional. Secure needs a boolean value and is optional. Skip these two and check by setting path to '/'

Comment: No, no headers already sent errors. I was under the impression that when I used javascript to redirect instead of the `header` function it didn't matter if I outputted beforehand anyways. Also, is `setcookie` as finicky as `header` is? Are you sure I cannot output anything before `setcookie`?

Comment: Ah, where is the path? When you setcookie you also specify path, from your JS, it seesm you are setting cookie in `a.com/folder/setcookie` which may not be available to `a.com/checkcookie` if you don't specify the path, default value for path is current working directory, set the path to '/' (slash) and then check

Comment: Got it. How do I set the path for the cookie?

Answer (score 2):

Probably because $userinfo is an array. It has to be a string, to store multiple items you need multiple cookies

Comment: He is serialising the array into a string.

Comment: @Johan No, `$userinfo = serialize($userinfo);` makes it comma-separated values instead, AKA a string.