# Why are my cookies not setting?

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following PHP function:

```
function validateUser($username){
    session_regenerate_id (); 
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    setcookie('username2',$username,time()+60*60*24*365);
    header("Location: ../new.php");
}
```

And then I fetch the cookie:

`echo $_COOKIE['username2']; exit();`

(I only put `exit()` for debugging purposes)

Only problem, it's coming out blank. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
This is how the function is called:

```
    if(mysql_num_rows($queryreg) != 0){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($queryreg,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $hash = hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));
    if($hash == $row['password']) {
        if($row['confirm'] == 1){
            if(isset($remember)){
                setcookie('username',$username,time()+60*60*24*365);
                setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*24*365);
            } else {
                setcookie('username','',time()-3600);
                setcookie('password','',time()-3600);
            }
            validateUser($username);
```

I didn't include all the `if()` statements to save some space.

Comment: You're looking for `$_COOKIE['username2']` on `new.php` ?

Comment: try echoing out the `$username` variable and check whether it contains any value or not.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Yes, on `new.php`

Comment: @Sayem yes, `$username` contains the username entered.

Comment: Is the validateUser function being run? Dumb question: your browser is set to allow cookies, right?

Comment: @Sayem yes, the login page has an in-depth cookies and JavaScript check.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` set? Try doing `echo $username; exit()'` to ensure the username actually has a value, and add `print_r($_COOKIE);` as the first thing on new.php

Comment: Deleted my answer after some local testing. Order of calling the functions doesn't matter. I also tested to see if it was a path issue, but that doesn't matter either. Can you call the page with "curl -I" to show what headers are being returned?

Comment: @AgentConundrum `$username` does have a value, and `print_r($_COOKIE);` shows no trace of the correct cookie.

Comment: Ok so I've concluded that the cookie is being lost somewhere in the redirect. I added the line `echo "Username: " . $_COOKIE['username2']; exit();` right before the end of the function, and sure enough the username was echoed out.

Comment: Where are you defining `$remember` for the line `if(isset($remember)){...`

Comment: add exit; after header ("location:  see if things change. even if it didn't it is better to do that. otherwise strange things could happen, if you don't want code after the function call to run.

Comment: Problem solved, I had to change it to `setcookie('username2',$username,time()+60*60*24*365,'/');` since the cookie had to be available on all paths, instead of only the current one.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942977/any-reason-why-this-code-snippet-wouldnt-set-a-cookie-properly/

Comment: The question is similar, but the answers in this thread are much more in depth and cover more possible issues. So I would not consider these two threads as duplicates.

Answer (score 57):

try adding the path = /, so that the cookie works for the whole site not just the current directory (that has caught me out before)

example

```
setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
```

also make sure the cookie is the first thing being output
as advised in the php manual (this has caught me out before too)

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your
>   script (this is a protocol restriction).

Comment: Just in case if you want to add cookie after you have outputted some text then add ob_start(); at the start of the script.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that if output has been sent to the browser already (headers_sent() == true) then the cookie won't set and there is no error!  It would be great if PHP at least gave a warning if setcookie() is used when output was already sent! However, apparently setcookie returns false if output is already sent so I should have checked the output: "If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie will fail and return false. If
 *   setcookie successfully runs, it will return true.
 *  This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie."

Answer (score 31):

### Why you are having this problem

The problem comes from the fact that setcookie() doesn't set the cookies *immediately*, it sends the headers so the browser sets the cookies. This means that, for the current page load, setcookie() will no generate any `$_COOKIE`.

When the browser later on requests a page, it sends the cookies in the headers so the PHP can retrieve them in the form of $_COOKIE.

### Simple, *old* solution

About solutions, the obvious one:

```
setcookie('username',$username,time()+60*60*24*365);
// 'Force' the cookie to exists
$_COOKIE['username'] = $username;
```

## A better solution

I created a class, `Cookie`, that addresses the problems that setcookie() and $_COOKIE share:

```
// Class that abstracts both the $_COOKIE and setcookie()
class Cookie
  {
  // The array that stores the cookie
  protected $data = array();

  // Expiration time from now
  protected $expire;
  // Domain for the website
  protected $domain;

  // Default expiration is 28 days (28 * 3600 * 24 = 2419200).
  // Parameters:
  //   $cookie: $_COOKIE variable
  //   $expire: expiration time for the cookie in seconds
  //   $domain: domain for the application `example.com`, `test.com`
  public function __construct($cookie, $expire = 2419200, $domain = null)
    {
    // Set up the data of this cookie
    $this->data = $cookie;

    $this->expire = $expire;

    if ($domain)
      $this->domain = $domain;
    else
      {
      $this->domain = 
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']) ?
        $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] :
        isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ?
          $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] :
          $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
      }
    }

  public function __get($name)
    {
    return (isset($this->data[$name])) ?
      $this->data[$name] :
      "";
    }

  public function __set($name, $value = null)
    {
    // Check whether the headers are already sent or not
    if (headers_sent())
      throw new Exception("Can't change cookie " . $name . " after sending headers.");

    // Delete the cookie
    if (!$value)
      {
      setcookie($name, null, time() - 10, '/', '.' . $this->domain, false, true);
      unset($this->data[$name]);
      unset($_COOKIE[$name]);
      }

    else
      {
      // Set the actual cookie
      setcookie($name, $value, time() + $this->expire, '/', $this->domain, false, true);
      $this->data[$name] = $value;
      $_COOKIE[$name] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$Cookie = new Cookie($_COOKIE);
$User = $Cookie->user;
$LastVisit = $Cookie->last;
$Cookie->last = time();
```

And of course, you have to pass it around. Much better than having globals.

Comment: I have my own cookie-creating class I have as well. A key difference though... if headers are already sent, instead of throwing an exception, I simply print some javascript that sets/updates the cookie and then update the $_COOKIE variable.

Comment: Hi Francisco, thank you for your explanation. One question, where are 'user', 'last' properties defined? It looks like they are assumed to be properties inside the class?

Comment: This is 10 years old... please read about `__get` here to understand the code:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Answer (score 8):

Here is the general syntax of setcookie

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure);
```

Look at third argument, if you do not set it the script will take it to current working directory. So if you set a cookie without setting path at `a.com/b/setcookie.php` the cookie will not be available to `a.com/checkcookie.php`. What you are doing is setting cookie in a subfolder and the redirecting to a parent folder, look at `../`, where it is not available hence the issue. How to avoid this? Normal procedure is to supply a path that is `/`, in your case supply `/` as fourth param. The fifth argument for your cookie will set it secure. http://www.php.net/setcookie has more explanation. This should fix your problem. Setting domain path to `domain.com`, will make the cookie available to everything under `domain.com` but not to `something.domain.com`. Set domain value to `.domain.com`, look at the dot preceding domain.com, will make it available across `anything.domain.com`. HTH!

Comment: '/' saved the day. I was getting no errors, just no saved cookies without `setcookie('threadcookie', $v_id,time()+3600, '/');` on the end of my string
THANKS !

Answer (score 5):

Thought I would add another possible reason why a cookie may not be either setting or showing random functional behavior.

The following case may be applicable to some programmers having what appears to be an illusive cookie setting issue as a result of the incorrect usage of `header_remove()`

If you try to set a cookie **before** calling `header_remove()`, the cookie will never be created because you have also immediately destroyed the header that was set in order to create the cookie before it was buffered out to the client.

You may find when fiddling around that your cookie suddenly works for an unknown reason, so you need to understand the **race-conditions** around headers:

---

1. On first run you set a cookie and don't call `header_remove()` at all.
2. On a second run you do call `header_remove()`

> You will find your cookie is now always set regardless of condition (2) and the number of times it is called because (1) happened first at least once.

> The cookie will remain set until it either **expires**, **is overwritten** or `unset()`

---

The same will apply when modifying headers like a cookie value before  the eventual call of `header_remove()`, you again will fail to set new values because they will be wiped before the response is buffered out to the user.

> You need to set cookies and any other headers for that matter after a `header_remove()` not before.

> Use `header_remove()` to cleanup ALL previously set headers in order to set new headers for a final output.

An example of scenario for such a case may be as follows:

> Use `header_remove()` to alter a hierarchy of HTTP Response codes for a RESTFUL API where you are using `axios` with `interceptors`.

1. Your application sets a 400+ header error first, should the application error out at any point of execution.
2. Modify the header to a 200 when final desired execution point has been reached & a valid response is expected.

> In such an event, it is likely you want to preserve all other previously set headers but clear out the HTTP Status (400?) code in order to set a new (200?) code for the final response.

If you try to set the header again in order to change the status code before removing the previously set header then you will get the *"Headers already sent"* error.

> You can remove specific headers with [header_remove](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php), here is how to unset the status code and set a new code in stages:

```php
     // Set a default status code
     http_response_code(500);

     // Boot Logic runs - if fails here 500 is returned

     // Authentication Logic - If unauthorized ?
     header_remove('HTTP/1.0'); // Clear previous 500
     http_response_code(401); // Set new status code

     // else ?

     // Return Data Logic - Success
     header_remove('HTTP/1.0'); // Clear previous 500
     http_response_code(200) // Set new status code
```

Answer (score 4):

This requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output, including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

this is how the structure looks

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Ahmed Moftah";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
<html>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache problem. Try closing the browser and opening a new one with the localhost file path. I had the same issue and my page was cached so the cookies weren't working, even though I could put in new code and see a change on the page. Very weird... Cleaning your cache might help, try that first. Then try a new browser, then try to go to your localhost:8080 index and hit refresh to see when the last page was modified.

If that doesn't fix it, try restarting LAAMP or XAAMP or whatever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with the session cookies are disabled.

You can navigate to your php.ini file(changes depending on server. Ubuntu 20.04's default is /etc/php/{X.x}/{apache2|[others]}/php.ini) and ensure that `session.use_cookies=1`

Restart your server and then try to set the cookie. They should immediately be available.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have sent header hereby making it impossible to set header for cookie.
It might be a simple solution of `ob_start()` at the start of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the $_COOKIE on the same request but you can get $_SESSION on the same request.

So the idea is

- Set the $username in both the session & cookie.
- Get the username from the session for the first time (if the same request)
- Unset session
- Always get the cookie from $_COOKIE from next request.

```
// Set Cookie
setcookie('username',$username,time()+60*60*24*365);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

//GET Cookies

if(!$_COOKIE['username']){
   $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   unset($_SESSION['username']);
}else{
   $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this is pretty old question but the same issue occured to me and mine was completely a different case. See here

[image]

It took long time to figure it out that why my cookie is not set in browser.

**P.S** - I had copied one of the VM with https but I was trying to execute copied VM without setting up the SSL and due to it was set to secure from server, cookie was not working. Either need https or need to change the highlighted setting on server for http.

Comment: Please explain in words what your screenshot is depicting.

Answer (score -1):

[Solution tested in XAMPP for PHP 8.0.19]
I modified the file *php.ini* and set `session.auto_start=1`. Keep in mind that i'm calling `session_set_cookie_params([param => value])` just before session_start() every time this functions appears in my code, in every file.

`session.auto_star`: Initialize session on request startup.

http://php.net/session.auto-start

Still studying and analysing the reason and functionality of this, it was kind of a serendipity.
Probably not the most secure solution.