# Cookie and Session errors?

Tags: php, session, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my cookies not setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting)

I have the following function to set a Cookie and two Sessions:

```
function validateUser($username) {
    session_regenerate_id (); 
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    setcookie('username2',$username,time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
    header("Location: ../new.php");
    exit();
}
```

However, on `new.php` I added `echo $_COOKIE['username2']; echo $_SESSION['username']; exit();` for debugging purposes. However, the cookie comes up as the wrong user, and the session comes up blank. It's as if the cookie can't change, since it has the same value every time, but it should contain the `$username` value, which is different every time.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: do you have `session_start()` at the top of both pages?