# Cookies don't maintain value?

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are my cookies not setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting)

I have the following function to set a Cookie and two Sessions:

```
function validateUser($username) {
    session_regenerate_id (); 
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    setcookie('username2',$username,time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
    header("Location: ../new.php");
    exit();
}
```

When the function is called:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($queryreg) != 0){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($queryreg,MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $row['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));
if($hash == $row['password']) {
    if($row['confirm'] == 1){
        if(isset($remember)){
            setcookie('username',$username,time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
            setcookie('password',$password,time()+60*60*24*365,'/');
        } else {
            setcookie('username','',time()-3600,'/');
            setcookie('password','',time()-3600,'/');
        }
        validateUser($username);
```

However, on `test.php` I added `echo $_COOKIE['username2']; exit();` for debugging purposes. However, the cookie comes up as jason, one of the two users, every time. No matter who is logged in.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974379/cookie-and-session-errors

Comment: Are you 1) actually calling the function `validateUser()`? 2) calling `session_start()` on the page that calls `validateUser()`?

Comment: Where about do you get the username & where do you unset the cookie if login is wrong, are you setting the cookie even if login is wrong? have you tried clearing your cookies and debugging abit more with some `var_dump()` and `die()` there is not much wrong with the above code...

Comment: @Michael yes, and yes.
@Lawrence it sets the cookie based on the `mysql_num_rows()` of a sql query. The username comes from the username field in the login page. And yes I have.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forgot to

```
session_start()
```

in your new.php

and to call your

```
validateUser()
```

function

Comment: Don't I have to only validate the user once, when they login? I only want to set all this data once

Comment: @Jason: 1. Do not save user's password into cookies 2.add else, are you sure it's going throught last shown if statement?

Comment: 1. How else do I store the users' passwords for a remember me checkbox? 2. Yes, it goes through every if statement there. The `if($row['confirm'] == 1)` checks if the user activated their account. If they didn't activate it, they're redirected.