# Using cookies to keep someone logged in

Tags: php, cookies

Okay im trying to make a remember me feature on a website so that when a user clicks the tickbox they are remberd. In the page where they log in I have the cookies set as the username and password:

```
setcookie('mail',$email,time() + 31536000); 
setcookie('pass',$password_h,time() + 31536000);
```

Then in my member home I have this IF statement so that it checks if the cookies are set in browser:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['password']) or isset($_COOKIE['mail']) && isset($_COOKIE['pass'])) 
{
} else {
echo 'access denied'
}
```

I have been trying to echo the cookies and it gives me this 
Notice: Undefined variable: COOKIE ....

Google chrome also says the cookies are not set in inspect element > Resource > Cookies

Any help is much appreciated
 as I am really struggling :)

Comment: Check that you aren't setting them after you've already output something else. Also you shouldn't set the password in the cookie. A better approach is to change the session expire time: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: This is how i am setting them if($login->num_rows == 1 and $f_password == $password_h){
  if ($_POST['stayloggedin'] == 'yes'){
  setcookie('mail',$email,time() + 31536000); 
  setcookie('pass',$password_h,time() + 31536000);
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
  $_SESSION['password'] = $password_h;
  //echo 'hmmm';
  header("Location: ../script/php/member_home.php");

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your IF statement isn't grouped...

Try this:

```
if ((isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])) or (isset($_COOKIE['mail']) && isset($_COOKIE['pass'])))
```

It groups the $_SESSION checks, and groups the $_COOKIE checks...  previously I'm not really sure how all the ANDs and ORs would play together.

Also, to check your cookies, comment out the redirect for now.   Put in echo ("Cookies are set") or something along that line.   This way you'll know your IF statement checking whether the cookies should be set is working.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting?rq=1) is a almost similar question.

Try adding the path = /, so that the cookie works for the whole site not just the current directory (that has caught me out before)

Comment: Ah thank you! :) Now the cookie comes up on the member home, but I still cant echo it, I get this: Notice: Undefined variable: COOKIE in C:\xampp\htdocs\Assignment_1_test\script\php\member_home.php on line 18 I am echoing both cookies like this echo $COOKIE['mail'];
echo $COOKIE['pass'];

Comment: echo $_COOKIE['email']. missing _ BEFORE COOKIE