# ISSET and ARRAY_KEY_EXISTS both return false

Tags: php, php-5.6

So I have some code. It looks like this:

```
if($_COOKIE['userid']!=null) {
    echo "<input value='" . $_COOKIE['userid'] . "' id = 'userIdField' class = 'proForma' type='text'/> ";
}else
{
    echo "<input value='' id = 'userIdField' class = 'proForma' type='text'/> ";
}
```

Checking for null is clunky, though, and I wanted to follow best practices. And it looked like those were using isset. Sensible. So I tried it. That code looked like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['userid'])){//do stuff}
```

But when that got evaluated, it always came out to false. I was looking at the developer tools, and userid definitely existed, definitely was set, but it was returning false. So I looked around some more, and saw that ISSET can be 'wonky' with $_COOKIE (no explanation of why was provided). The recommendation was that ARRAY_KEY_EXISTS would get me what I wanted. Now, it wouldn't check to see if the value was set, but for my use case, if the cookie name existed, the value would be set and I could proceed.

That code looked like this:

```
if(array_key_exists("userid", $_COOKIE)){//do stuff}
```

Also no dice. I tried it with single quotes, no dice.

So. I'm working with PHP version 5.6. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did you find this info about `wonky` cookies

Comment: StackOverflow. I'll see if I can find the post.

Comment: Is this any help http://stackoverflow.com/a/18936052/2310830 You dont mention if this test is just after doing a `setcookie()` or after the page returns the cookie

Comment: never heard `isset` function being _wonky_

Comment: isset would only be _wonky_ if the value in `$_COOKIE['userid'];` is `NULL` otherwise `array_key_exists()` does the same thing

Comment: That's pretty much why I'm asking this question. These are things that to all appearances *should* work, but they manifestly *don't*. I'm looking for reasons.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, the cookie has been set. I'm literally looking at it, in developer tools, while PHP is telling me "I don't have a cookie named that."

Comment: And if you echo the cookie using PHP you get what you expect?

Comment: echo $_COOKIE['userid']; gives me the ID number, as I would expect.