# Cookie set but disappears

Tags: php, cookies

Since a few weeks, I notice that my website doesn't save cookie anymore.

If I refresh a few times this page:

```
<?php 
print_r($_COOKIE);
setcookie('Test', 'Blah', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, '/');
print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

cookies should be there! But I get:

> Array ( ) Array ( )

**Is there a common way to debug this?**

*Note: it's not a duplicate from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting), its answers didn't solve the problem.*

Comment: The other question's answers doesn't solve this problem.

Comment: Open network tools in your browser. Check that the response headers for the cookie. It could be your browser, it could be a previous malformed header. Very hard for us to debug remotly

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Can you show where/what to look? Maybe a screenshot? (firefox or chrome) ?

Comment: I tested on another server: it works. What could be the  server problem?

Answer (score 2):

`$_COOKIE` contains the cookies that the browser sent in the *current* request.

`setcookie` puts an instruction *in the response* that tells the browser to store a cookie.

The browser won't send that cookie back to the server until the **next** request.

If you want to test if a cookie is set you can:

- Look at the response headers in your browser's developer tools
- Add some JavaScript to the response body that will examine `document.cookie`
- Make a new HTTP request and use server side code to see if it includes the cookie

Comment: Ok but then, if I refresh the page, the cookied should be shown, right? It's not.

Answer (score 1):

Set where you want the cookie to be accessible,

```
setcookie('Test', 'Blah', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365 * 10, "/");
```

`/` means that it is available everywhere on the domain.

**Path**

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

Try refresh the page as it doesn't show until next request.

**Reading Material**

[`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Answer (score -1):

try not to save it for 10 years . 1 year is already enough i belive

```
setcookie('Test', 'Blah', time() + 3600 * 24 * 365, "/");
```

Comment: It didn't change anything.