# Cookie not storing on users browser, php 7, Google App Engine [GAE]

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cookies

I have a strange issue. Pardon me, I have not seen any solution to it online. I seem not to be able to set and store cookie on users browsers on Google App Engine, PHP.

On localhost it works perfectly, on Godaddy it also works perfectly, but after migrating to Google cloud, it doesn't work again, I use PHP 5 on localhost, while the runtime[What the PHP version is] for GAE is PHP 7.

This is what i use to create cookie on users browsers

```
 $cookie_name = "bla_bla_bla";
 setcookie('browsing_tracker', $cookie_name, time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

This is what I use to remove the cookie.

```
 setcookie("browsing_tracker", "", time() - 3600);
```

But it does not work, no cookie is stored on the users browser.

I made an EDIT, added a PHP.INI file, also stored the cookie as this, it still did not work out.

New cookie setting style

```
$cookie_name = "bla_bla_bla";
setcookie('browsing_tracker', $cookie_name, time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
```

php.ini file

```
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.cookie_path = /
```

Comment: According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path you can try enclosing the / in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
 $cookie_name = "bla_bla_bla";
 setcookie('shopping_tracker', $cookie_name, time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
```

Not setting the `path` mostly prevents the cookie from being created.

Comment: See the following information, which confirms this theory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970754/why-are-my-cookies-not-setting

Comment: @MrTech thanks for your comment, ut it is not working.

Comment: @WanPeninsula did not work at all, still not setting, edited my Php.ini file still not luck.

Comment: @MrTech I already did like 4 days ago, we are working on it, seems its a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. Please use a [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) to report this behavior.This forum is meant for programming advice but reporting an issue is the way to go.