# Front controller preventing cookie from being created on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cookies

This is a followup on my last question [see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586479/cookie-not-storing-on-users-browser-php-7-google-app-engine-gae).

To recap, **I WAS NOT ABLE TO STORE COOKIE** on my website hosted on Google App Engine with Php 72 runtime, that works on localhost and godaddy, after migrating my hosting to google app engine it stopped working.

Now, after 2 days of debugging I tested `setcookie` on front controller, and it worked, the cookie was created, this is what I use to create cookies in PHP on my website.

```
setcookie('test_cookie', 'this cookie is not okay', time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
```

**MY QUESTION:** How do I set the main pages of my website to create the cookies not front controller that was referenced in my app.yaml file. I mean, instead of using front controller for cookie creation, I can use any page to create my cookies.

I want to be able to create cookie on index.php, about.php, contact.php instead of relying on my google app engine front controller which is worker.php. [**SEE APP.YAML** file below check the entry point that's the front controller]

app.yaml file

```
runtime: php72
runtime_config:
document_root:
handlers:
 - url: /.*
   script: auto
   secure: always
   redirect_http_response_code: 301

entrypoint: 
serve worker.php //this is the front controller
```

**EDIT:** added the set cookie code to index.php, about.php and contact.php did not work, still can only be created via front controller which is worker.php.

```
index.php 
<?php
 setcookie('test_cookie', 'this cookie is not okay', time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
?>    
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index.php</h1>
</body>
</html>


about.php 
<?php
 setcookie('test_cookie', 'this cookie is not okay', time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
?>    
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>about.php</h1>
</body>
</html>


contact.php 
<?php
 setcookie('test_cookie', 'this cookie is not okay', time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
?> 
<html>
<head>   
</head>
<body>
<h1>contact.php</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set them in each individual page.  Put this at the top:

```
<?php

setcookie('test_cookie', 'this cookie is not okay', time() + (3000 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");

?>
```

You can make an `include` file, too:

```
<?php include 'cookie_setter.php';?>
```

and put the common `setcookie(...)` code in the include.

**UPDATE AFTER OP EDIT:**

Try putting the code at the top of the page, outside of the `<HEAD>` tags.  It will make it easier to debug.  You have lots of errors that may be conflicting:  https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sharyor.com%2F

Lots of javascript errors, too.

Comment: Its added on all pages.

Comment: What url are you using?  Do you have a custom domain, like "my_site.com", or are you using the "appspot.com" domain?

Comment: I am using my own custom domains https://www.sharyor.com

Comment: I am using my own custom domain sharyor.com

Comment: the js errors and link errors are not errors they are google spfjs [STRUCTURED PAGE FRAGEMENTATION JAVASCRIPT], the code is outside the head tag, on my file let me edit my question.